# Casting a variable to a method in Scala "Runtime Evaluation"

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, casting, eval

I want to evaluate a function passed as a variable string in scala (sorry but i'm new to scala )

```
def concate(a:String,b:String): String ={
  a+" "+b
}
var func="concate" //i'll get this function name from config as string
```

I want to perform something like

```
eval(func("hello","world)) //Like in Python
```

so output will be like

> hello world

Eventually I want to execute few in built functions on a string coming from my config and I don't want to hard code the function names in the code.

> EDIT

To Be More clear with my exact usecase
I have a Config file which has multiple functions defined in it that are Spark inbuilt functions on Data frame 
application.conf looks like

```
  transformations = [
  {
    "table" : "users",
    "function" : "from_unixtime",
    "column" : "epoch"
  },
  {
    "table" : "users",
    "function" : "yearofweek",
    "column" : "epoch"
  }
]
```

Now functions yearofweek and from_unixtime are Spark inbuilt functions now I want to eval my Dataframe by the functions defined in config. #all the functions are applied to a column defined.
the Obvious way is to write an if else and do string comparison calling a particular inbuilt function but that is way to much..
i am looking for a better solution.

Comment: What is the reason behind such a requirement? Do you want to achieve specifically this or Is this your idea for solving the actual problem? Are you sure this is not - [The XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ?

Comment: Your question does not have anything to do with **casting**.

Comment: @Jesper actually it has a lot to do with casting. Look at pamu's answer. If `foo` and `bar` are functions with different signatures then most ideas towards a solution will run into a `type` problem.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Eventually I want to execute few in built functions on a string coming from my config and I don't want to hard code the function names in the code.

Comment: If all your functions are in-built, try to generate a SQL query by reading the JSON, maybe ?

Comment: You should have mentioned earlier that you are working with Spark SQL and UDF's. This is totally different from Scala functions.

Comment: you may also look into scala's quasi-quotes, that could be interesting

Comment: @RaphaelRoth thanks that looks interesting....:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is indeed possible in scala, as scala is JSR 223 compliant scripting language. Here is an example (running with scala 2.11.8). Note that you need to import your method because otherwise the interpreter will not find it:

```
package my.example

object EvalDemo {

  // evalutates scala code and returns the result as T
  def evalAs[T](code: String) = {
    import scala.reflect.runtime.currentMirror
    import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
    val toolbox = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
    import toolbox.{eval, parse}
    eval(parse(code)).asInstanceOf[T]
  }

  def concate(a: String, b: String): String = a + " " + b

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

    var func = "concate" //i'll get this function name from config as string

    val code =
      s"""
         |import my.example.EvalDemo._
         |${func}("hello","world")
         |""".stripMargin

    val result: String = evalAs[String](code)

    println(result) // "hello world"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have Function to name mapping in the code

```
def foo(str: String) = str + ", foo"
def bar(str: String) = str + ", bar"

val fmap = Map("foo" -> foo _, "bar" -> bar _)

fmap("foo")("hello")
```

now based on the function name we get from the config, pass the name to the map and lookup the corresponding function and invoke the arguments on it.

Scala repl

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def foo(str: String) = str + ", foo"
def bar(str: String) = str + ", bar"

val fmap = Map("foo" -> foo _, "bar" -> bar _)

fmap("foo")("hello")


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

foo: (str: String)String
bar: (str: String)String
fmap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String => String] = Map(foo -> $$Lambda$1104/1335082762@778a1250, bar -> $$Lambda$1105/841090268@55acec99)
res0: String = hello, foo
```

Comment: What happens when `foo` and `bar` have different signatures ?

Comment: @pamu that might not serve my purpose because here functions might be inbuilt functions which i dont want to insert in map manually

Comment: @KalpishSinghal Things like "might be" do not apply to a structured thing like programming. Can you clearly specify your use-case?

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh
 In my usecase I have a config
 transformations = [
  {
    "table" : "users",
    "function" : "from_unix_timestamp",
  },
  {
    "table" : "users",
    "function" : "yearofweek"
  }
]

both the fuctions yearofweek, from_unix_timestamp are internal implementation of Spark Scala I want to pick anyone of this and on the same table/DF column. so to generalize the problem my Question remains the same .i.e eval of a function at run time. and Since i have familiarity to python programming paradigms this has trivial solution is python .but not sure about Scala

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh please check edit if you want a more clear explanation to my problem use-case.

Answer (score 0):

Spark offers you a way to write your transformations or queries using SQL. So, you really don't have to worry about Scala functions, casting and evaluation in this case. You just have to parse your config to generate the SQL query.

Let's say you have registered a table `users` with Spark and want to do a select and transform based on provided config,

```
// your generated query will look like this,
val query = "SELECT from_unixtime(epoch) as time, weekofyear(epoch) FROM users"

val result = spark.sql(query)
```

So, all you need to do is - build that `query` from your config.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question. The question is all about how to generate that query from the JSON.

Comment: @philantrovert Well... please take some time to read the question title, question language and comments. And enlighten me where did you arrive at conclusion that -  "The question is all about how to generate that query from the JSON"

Comment: Well, even if my conclusion is wrong, the question doesn't say **"How to execute a SQL query in Spark"** either. It's an incorrect answer either way.

Comment: If it is like that then you are obviously entitled to hold that opinion. I am more interested in helping him to solve the problem.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh That solves the problem upto some extend although I was looking for a Scala based solution thr again i need to fromulate a SQL query from config that might be a way to solve it ...
thanks :)
but again things might be restrictive while using SQL in one way or another but  it seems ok for time being

Comment: @KalpishSinghal Looking at your config example, I am sure you are working with Spark SQL and if you are using Spark SQL then yes you will be limited by limitations of Spark SQL. If you use any technology, you will be restricted by it, same with Spark and Spark SQL. There is no "scala based" solution to it (at least not one which will not take weeks to build).